# Can we calculate the upper bound of needed power from some information from datasheet?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, datasheet

This is a energy harvester product data sheet, and we can know some information below

https://www.powercastco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/P1110B-Datasheet-Rev-4.pdf

[image]

1.\$V_{out} \$ current = 100mA

2.\$V_{out} \$ voltage = 4.3V

First,we all know that we need some energy to start up the circuit,if this circuit is "off",it can't work,i mean,it can't harvest energy to charge itself.So we can know that this device has to have some energy to let itself in "on" state,then it can begin working!

I assume this device wants to harvest the energy to charge its battery,and this battery is also the device's power supply,if there isn't a power supply,the harvested circuit won't work.So the power supply needs to has some energy,\$E_{ini}\$,first to startup the circuit.And what i want to know is that what is the upper bound value or lower bound value of that \$E_{ini}\$

Is there anyway that can calculate  the upper bound value or lower bound value of \$E_{ini}\$ when we only have some information from its datasheet?

Comment: I can't really understand your calculation, but I can assure you that if this is a power harvesting IC: 0.4 W is way more than it'd ever need to start up. A maximum damage-free current sourcing ability has nothing to do with power consumption.

Comment: In addition to the "input power" limitation to 200 mW, mote that these are the "abs max" ratings. It isn't guaranteed to operate at these levels; but if they are exceeded it is likely to be destroyed.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, this gizmo is self-powered. A battery-powered energy harverster would indeed be hilarious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my thinking reasonable?

No, because maximum RF input power is 23 dBm. That's 200 mW and that is all the power you could ever harvest. You can never simultaneously draw 100 mA at an output voltage of 4.3 volts. Please also remember that harvesting is never 100% efficient so you should be thinking around a maximum of 100 mW.

Minimum operating power is quoted as -5 dBm and that is 0.316 mW or, if that power were terminated in 50 ohms, is a voltage of 126 mV RMS.

Comment: So you mean that if the battery has 0.316 mW ,it  can startup or maintain this energy harvester in  on  state?

Comment: Have you ever seen a battery specified as having x mW of power? I never have. Power is what you can energize (or charge) a battery with and, after some significant reduction, is the power you can extract from the battery. It's always better to talk about charge current or energy.

Comment: i assume time is 1 second ,so power will be equal to the energy.So you mean if a battery which has 0.316 mJ,it can  startup or maintain this energy harvester in on state?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "on state".

Comment: "on" state  means the device is still alive,can work

Comment: The minimum RF power value is the power from an RF source and not from a battery. That minimum power is 0.316 mW and might be approximately equivalent to an RMS input voltage of 126 mV and is nothing to do with a battery.

Comment: well i think you misunderstand what i want to say ,maybe i need to revise my question

Comment: I have edited the question,sorry to let you misunderstand my meaning

Comment: @XM551 the data sheet is very poor at explaining what hold-up voltage is needed on the battery to keep the circuit alive. The only hint is that it will work "from 0 volts" and that it will take 1.5 uA from the external battery. On that basis alone I'd want to pick a device that was clearer in its data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The table you are referring to is **Absolute maximum**. I would insist to have a look at the recommended characteristics
[image]

One more point is that, when you are trying to draw maximum current, the as per the specification the voltage will not be 4.2V. The graphs are good references than the table.

[image]

- The maximum input power is \$20 dBm\$
- The efficiency maximum (missing in the table) is about **50%** at maximum input power.

  ---

Update 2: The only reference in datasheet is the below graphs
[image]

depending on the set \$V_{OUT}\$ value, \$-5dBm\$ or \$-3dBm\$. Please write to them for confirmation.

Comment: I think you mis-understand what i really want to ask,if there isn't a power supply,the harvested circuit won't work.So the power supply needs to has some energy,\$E_{ini}\$, to startup the circuit.And what i want to know is that what is the upper bound value or lower bound value of that \$E_{ini}\$